# Difference between _extend.less . and _extends.less

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, less, grunt

While working on a custom theme with blank parent theme , I noticed strange behaviors:
First of all, gulp and grunt give a different output. Mostly these are parts of code in different order (on gulp's output, the parts are below to grunt's output).
Also, comparing only these code parts, there are differences. ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeU9u.jpg))
With the help of sourcemaps it would seem that the code comes from

> "pub / static / frontend / vendor / theme / en_US / css / source /
>   _extends.less"

This comes from the default blank theme.
Normally, Magento uses "_extend.less" files for less instructions extending existing styles. 
But why use "_extends.less"? 
I noticed it existed only in this position and only on the blank theme.

The styles-l.less load this file like this:

> @import (reference) 'source / _extends.less';

Is there a particular reason for its use?

**UPDATE**

Removing extends.less from blank theme, gulp's output and grunt's output are the same.

A possible workaround could be to remove the extends.less file and then have the same result with both.

However, there is still a doubt as to why this file was inserted (and why in this way).

Comment: I think ```_extends.less``` is only a less partial with a confusing name that is not related to the ```_extend.less``` mechanism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a further study, the extends.less file would appear to be an additional file used only as a "container" of abstract classes.
So all abstract classes used or newer should be write in this file.

The problem apparently originates from a wrong compiler's interpretation (I think the nesting between more ":extend").

I opened a new question for [solve-problems-with-different-magento2-less-compilation-outputs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189081/solve-problems-with-different-magento2-less-compilation-outputs)